# Create multilevel Dask dataframe from multiple parquet files

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I have a folder with around 500 CSV files. Each parquet file was created by saving a test result that looks as follows (time series of multiple variables where each file might contain around 50,000 rows).

[image]

My final goal is to plot a specific parameter versus time from all the files (can't know ahead which parameter). For example, to read 500 files and plot reg vs t that will look like this:

[image]

In order to make sure that each line in the plot will be separate, I used a multilevel Pandas DataFrame.I used the following code to do so:

```
folder =  os.listdir(os.path.splitext(os.getcwd()+'/results')[0])

comp = {i.split('.')[0]: pd.read_csv('results/'+i, index_col='t') for i in folder}
combined = pd.concat(comp, axis=0)

plt.plot(combined.unstack(level=0)['reg'])
plt.show()
```

Since my data is pretty large and it becomes pretty slow to load and plot, I would like to use Dask in order to read the files in a parallel way. Also, I would like to switch to parquet files instead of CSV.

Is there any way to read 500 parquet files (say I saved the CSV files in a parquet format) and store them as a multilevel Dask Dataframe so I will achieve the same result but using parallel computation?

Thank you